# What is the "Rails way" of versioning a table at a set interval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, whenever, database-versioning

I have a model that looks like this:

```rb
class WidgetStack < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :widget
  belongs_to :person

  validates :quantity, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, only_integer: true }
end
```

All the table consists of is those two foreign keys and that `quantity` bigint. **`quantity` can only increase, and potentially changes thousands of times a day.**

I want to make a record of the state of the `widget_stacks` table every hour, on the hour, so that I can report on the changes to each `WidgetStack`'s quantity over the last hour, day, week, month, etc.

My inclination is to make a `WidgetStacksHistory` model and table, and then use the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to hourly `create` a `WidgetStackHistory` record for every `WidgetStack`.

I also found the [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) gem, which does model versioning, but I don't think it's for me because a `WidgetStack`'s `quantity` changes so often and I need the record taken every hour on the hour, for every `WidgetStack` at the same time. There will be a lot of `WidgetStacks`, and I don't need/want to record every single change. Furthermore, since I need the exact `quantity` every hour on the hour, if I used [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail), I'd have to record every single change to make sure that I had the latest data on the hour.

What's the "Rails way" of taking periodic snapshots of a table like this? Is my `WidgetStacksHistory` + [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) solution the way to go?

**UPDATE** with more info:

To clarify regarding the data: When I capture the data, it needs to fully include every `WidgetStack`, so three bigints (two foreign keys plus `quantity`), and the `created_at` timestamp for each `WidgetStack`. There will potentially be thousands of `WidgetStack`s. I need to store the data with at least hourly granularity for the last day, daily granularity for the last month, and monthly granularity indefinitely.

Comment: Would you please explain what you expect the data to look like when you capture it, how long you need to store it, and how large the dataset is for each capture (byte size + record count)?

Comment: @anothermh Sure, updated my question with more info.

Comment: I'd go with your inclination.  You're right, `papertrail` is not meant for this sort of historical reporting of data state.

Comment: Are you using Postgres? If so, would https://github.com/palkan/logidze work?

Comment: @anothermh That looks like a great tool and I'd try it in place of paper_trail, so thanks for bringing it to my attention. But it looks like it serves the same purpose as paper_trail, so I think for this particular issue, my whenever-based solution is probably the way to go.

Comment: I think your own solution, a WidgetStackHistory model and table is exactly the right approach. Rails is not prescriptive for everything. Your concept is entirely consistent with "the Rails way".